# how to take span value which inside <td>(table data),when click button that also inside <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

i cant understand how to take inside table **span** id value and also **span** text when click a button that also in same row

my html code is

```
<div>
<table id="t1" style="border:1px solid">       
    <tr><td><span id="city">Chikago</span></td><td><span>USA</span></td><td><button class="show">Show me</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span id="city">London</span></td><td><span>UK</span></td><td><button class="show">Show me</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span id="city">Delhi</span></td><td><span>INDIA</span></td><td><button class="show">Show me</button></td></tr>

</table>
```

using jquery,i am trying to take 2bd row,2nd column  value when click the  button of 2nd row but i cant understand how to select tanle roes,columns data.

thats why i cant write jquery code.

please give a proper jquery code for this problem.

Comment: Have you already written the click event for the button? -- if so please share this.  I dont think you can expect to good folks on SO to do all your work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the spans in the same row. Also, don't reuse `id`s in your HTML elements.

```js
$(".show").on("click", function() {
  var spans = $(this).closest("tr").find("span");
  var city = spans.eq(0).text();
  var country = spans.eq(1).text();
  console.log(city, country);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1" style="border:1px solid">       
  <tr><td><span>Chikago</span></td><td><span>USA</span></td><td><button type="button" class="show">Show me</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>London</span></td><td><span>UK</span></td><td><button type="button" class="show">Show me</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>Delhi</span></td><td><span>INDIA</span></td><td><button type="button" class="show">Show me</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have each id as a unique value - all those spans have the same id and will cause problems - I would recommend using data-attributes, which could be in the same td as the city name as in the following:

```
<td data-id="city">Chikago</td>
```

Then on the click of the button - you need to get the data attribute and text of the one td.

Comment: ... or <td class="city"... then it can be used in css for styling.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to keep in mind that there can only be one id per document. Think of it this way

`classes`: Classify an element based on their characteristics

`ids`: Are a unique identification badge for the element. It can say "Hey, I'm element number 158493 and I take pride in that!"

Moving forward, listen for the `click` event on elements classified as `show`. To find the actual city name, you have to traverse up the DOM. First get the parent and then its older brother with `prev()`. This will get you the previous `td` element. Now traverse downward to its child which is the span element.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".show").on("click", function() {
  var cityValue = $(this).parent().prev().find("span").html();
  $("#city-value").html(cityValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="t1" style="border:1px solid">       
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="city">Chikago</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>USA</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="show">Show me</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="city">London</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>UK</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="show">Show me</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="city">Delhi</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>INDIA</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="show">Show me</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
  
<p id="city-value"></p>
```